# Django model reference to self class

Tags: django, django-models, mptt

I have a model, like this (simplified):

```
class Project(TimeStampedModel, StartFinishModel):
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    budget = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11)

class Task():
   name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
   parent = TreeForeignKey('self',
                            on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                            related_name='children')
   project = models.ForeignKey('prosystem.Project',
                                related_name='tasks',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  @property
  def current_budget(self):
     # this does not work now
     sumz = self.cls.objects.filter(project = self.project).aggregate(Sum('budget'))
     return sumz
```

The question is - **how can I filter all instances of `Task` model from its own `current_budget` property?** I know there might be some *meta.class* reference, but can't find info about that. Thank you for any advices.

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want here? Filter on the total budget?

Comment: Furthermore the `current_budget` is rather strange. You sum over the `budget`s of the `Task`s with the same `project`?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem exactly. Project has total budget. I want do add new Tasks with their budgets and I want to verify it sum of all Tasks budgets, which belong to 1 Project - does not exceed Project's total budget. The purpose of this property - is count the current budget of all sub tasks and verify if new provided budget can be added without exceeding that total budget from Project. Sorry for a small mess :)

Comment: But here your `current_budget` implementation suggests that you sum over the *tasks* not the `budget` in the `Project` (that is shown after the edit).

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  1) I want to add Task. -> 2) I verify if there is budget available for it -> 3) From `Task` model I get its `Project` model and find all `Tasks` that already belongs to that `Project` -> 4) I make a sum of all budgets of that tasks and check if that sum does not already exceed total Project budget (not in this piece of code).

Comment: Ah ok, that makes it more clear. Thanks :)

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  any advices for that? :)

Comment: Well you can annotate the budget left, like `.annotate(left=F(project__budget) - F('project__tasks__budget')).filter(left__gt=cost)`, to check if that is possible. But wouldn't you want to *orient* this on the `Project`s? Here you will get the `Task`s that belong to a project that has enough money left.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem  what do you mean with *orient*? Move that property to a `Project` model?

Comment: Yes, `Project.objects.annotate(left=F('budget')-Sum('tasks__budget')).filter(left__gt=1000)` will for example yield all projects where there is still 1000 budget left.

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem ok, I will think about that, thank you

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem I found what i wanted - `self.__class__.objects.filter(project = self.project).aggregate(Sum('budget'))`. OMG I was so close :)